# Problems with opening ports on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, port

Basically I have tried every tutorial I could find but I can't seem to open a port in a Linux VM.

- I tried downloading gufw and opening a port there; didn't work.
- I disabled gufw; didn't work
- Set a rule in iptables to allow inbound traffic from chosen port;
  didn't work
- All of the above; didn't work

Whenever I scan with zenmap it always shows all ports are closed.
When I use nc -l -p port and scan that port with nmap it shows open? and warnings like "Port sent RST packet."

So yeah, I am clueless. Any suggestions?

More details on my failed attempts:
I downloaded gufw and accessed the gui, then I clicked on the + sign and added a rule that allowed tcp and udp to the chosen port. Then I rebooted and scanned it with nmap and saw that it didn't work.

I wrote sudo ufw disable, rebooted and scanned it with zenmap and every port was closed.

I used this command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport port -j ACCEPT
```

and then

```
iptables-save
```

and then rebooted.
Again, it failed.

I haven't done much to the Linux VM in the matters of networking, firewalls, etc... besides from downloading gufw but even when I disable that it doesn't work so that's probably not the problem.

Also, I am using VMWare Player and the VM is connected to the network in Bridged mode.

Comment: Is there a service listening on the port in question? It sounds like when you tested with nc, it worked.

Comment: It doesn't matter; the result is the same whenever the port is 80 or 12334. The terminal window does show messages like HELP or GET / HTTP\1.1 when I scan with nmap, so I assume the ports are open, but only for nc it seems.

Comment: What I mean is that they are only open when I have nc listening on them, the problem is that they are always closed no matter how I configure the firewall. As far as I know, the defaults when you don't have a firewall is that all ports are open

Comment: Does the service work on localhost and not externally?  It sounds like there's nothing bound to the port you're testing.

Comment: If there's no service bound to a port, it will show as closed.  This is expected behavior.